# Is there a way to skip a URL (Json file) when I don't have access or there is no information available

Tags: python, json, url, python-requests

I am running a function that retrieves JSON files from individual URLs. However, some of the files no longer exist or I don't have access (webpage showing only "Unauthenticated"). Either way, there is no available information on that URL. I realise the if and else below make no sense but I have included it to show what I am trying to do.

```
def data (ticker):
    url = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/{ticker}.LSE?api_token".format(ticker=ticker)

    with requests.get(url, verify=True) as response:
        data = response.json()
    
    if len(data)>1:
        print (data)
        
    else:
        skip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the status code and decide what to do in each case. For example:

```
def data(ticker):
    url = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/{ticker}.LSE?api_token".format(ticker=ticker)

    with requests.get(url, verify=True) as response:
        if response.status_code == 401: 
            print("Not authorized")
        elif response.status_code == 404:
            print("Not found")
        else:
            data = response.json()
            # your logic
```

You can explore the `response` object and use it to define more fine grained behaviour (for example: use the `reason` attribute or print the content of the response).